# How can I identify bcc sender in Outlook?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

In Outlook is it possible to view the "bcc" sender's list for the mail which I have received?

Background:

My colleague often sends email to me with hidden bcc list which lead to some consequences.

Comment: No, that's the sole purpose of BCC: **blind** carbon copy. [Maybe if you have access to the mail server](http://superuser.com/questions/345285/is-bccing-e-mails-guaranteed-to-be-reliable).

Comment: I got the feeling that you ask one question (how do I see something which I can not see) while trying to solve a quite different problem. 

Why does your colleague use BCC:?

Does he perhaps misclick CC: and does not understand the difference?  Did he or she learn to use that for quite useful cases (e.g. newletters where you do not want to expose all the addresses or the name or internal mailinglists which are not supposed to be public or with limited access) and now used that for everything? 

What is the actual problem which you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> In outlook
>   is it possible to view the "bcc" sender's list for the mail which i have received?

No. It is not possible in **any** mail program. The whole idea is that this information is not sent to the mails receivers. What you do not have you can not show, regardless which mail client you use.

> Is it possible to detect BCC list for the mail which I have received at outlook

No, since you do not receive it. At best you can take action on things like
"mail received without me in the TO: field". Or maybe a rule based on "without me in the TO: field or the CC: field".

Comment: Just to note for those coming from Google on a related search. If you are the sender you can via the BCC field in your original sent email. You just have to turn on the BCC option.