# Email sent to me is addressed to MAIL@MAIL.COM. How is this done?

Tags: email, metadata

I was recently sent a scam email, and for giggles I opened it up to read it. Very plain, and not much effort thrown in.

I noticed something peculiar; this email was not addressed to me.
At first, I suspected a CC, or a BCC, but nowhere does it have my address on the mail. I have provided a picture below. How is this done?

[image]

Comment: Post the full message headers... also you may have a secondary SMTP address on the email server that this was sent to perhaps. Email server admins should be able to help advise you on this but [edit] you answer and post the full message header detail of this message too.

Comment: You were probably in the [blind carbon copy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blind_carbon_copy) field of the email.

Comment: You won't see the BCC list, [that's the "B"lind part](https://superuser.com/questions/977537/how-can-i-identify-bcc-sender-in-outlook). ;)

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 but wouldn't I at least see myself?

Comment: @tuskiomi No, not in Outlook. Gmail does show `bcc: me`, perhaps others do as well...But if you look at the full message headers you should see your email there

Comment: @tuskiomi - No, you will never see anyone listed in BCC, not even yourself. Moreover, if it's spam, there may not even be a true BCC list; spamware can manage the recipient list any way it wants, and what ultimately matters is what the spamware's dialogue with the mail server looks like - not what the content of the mail is. The only way you'll see your email address is if you look at the internet headers.

Comment: Someone can take a message from Alice to Bill and mail it to Charlie if they want to. Heck, I can compose a fake letter from God to the Pope and mail it to you if I want.

Comment: Cross-stack see https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/9487/how-can-paypal-spoof-emails-so-easily-to-say-it-comes-from-someone-else

Comment: _"At first, I suspected a CC, or a BCC, but nowhere does it have my address on the mail."_ Well, if it was a BCC, then you wouldn't. That's the whole point.

Comment: Most likely a spam sender does not use the Bcc mechanism. The actual machinism used is that he was in the envelop-to of the SMTP transmission. The Mail is delivered regardless of beeing listed in To or Cc or not.

Comment: Is that image real? I would recommend editing it to remove your actual name and email address. Also, why on earth did you reply to it?

Comment: I can't comment due to lack of reputation but I actually worked at the Service Desk @ UofSC. Forward that email to phishing@sc.edu and IT Security can prevent further emails from the sender from being sent to other students and faculty. Also, you may want to remove your email from being publicly listed from sc.edu/directory. You can make the change at my.sc.edu.

Answer (score 150, accepted):

An Internet e-mail message consists of two parts. We can refer to them as the *envelope* and the *payload message* or simply *message*.

**The envelope has routing data:** primarily, this is the sender address and one or more recipient addresses.

**The message has the message content:** subject line, message body, attachments, and so on. It also carries some technical information such as trace (`Received:`) headers, DKIM data, and so on; as well as the *displayed* sender and recipient addresses (what you see in the `From`, `To` and `Cc` fields in your mail client).

Here's the crux of it: **The two don't have to agree!**

A mail server will look at the envelope data to determine how to send the message. On the other hand, with few exceptions, the message itself will be treated as just data. Particularly, a well-behaved mail server *does not* look at the `To:` and `Cc:` fields of the message itself to determine the list of recipients, nor does it look at the `From:` field to determine the sender's address.

When you compose and send an e-mail, **your e-mail client takes what you entered into the To, Cc and Bcc fields, and translates that into envelope routing information.** This is mainly done by removing any full names (leaving only e-mail addresses), but can also involve things like address rewriting, alias expansion, and so on. The result is a list of e-mail addresses which are given to the mail server your mail client is talking to as the list of recipients. The To and Cc lists are kept in the e-mail, but the Bcc is not passed along to the server, making it invisible to message recipients. **The sender address works very similarly.**

When the message reaches its final destination, the envelope data is either thrown away, or retained in the detailed message headers. That's one part of the reason why Spittin' IT asked for the full message headers in a comment to your question.

Additionally, with Internet e-mail, it is possible to talk directly to a mail server, and thus inject a message that has a mismatch between the envelope data and the message data that a normal, *well-behaved* e-mail client wouldn't let you compose. Also, **mail servers do varying degrees of checks on the sender address that they are given in the envelope data; some barely check it at all** beyond making sure it's a *syntactically* valid e-mail address. **The From header of the message data is subjected to even less scrutiny.**

Since the receiving e-mail client displays what's in the From, To and Cc headers, not the address data from the envelope, **it's possible to put anything you want there** and the receiving e-mail client will have no recourse but to trust that it is reasonably accurate. For legitimate mail it usually is accurate enough; for spam, it almost never is.

**In the world of tangible, physical objects inhabited by us mere humans,** the *envelope sender* and *envelope recipient* corresponds to the return address and recipient address, respectively, that you write on the outside of the envelope; and the `From:` and `To:`/`Cc:` headers correspond to whatever you put as your and the recipient's addresses, respectively, in the letter which you put in the envelope.

Comment: I wish people made more real-world analogies here so others would understand what the physical equivalent is. The "sender" of an email is like the person handing the mailman the envelope; the "from" address is the one it's intended to be from. Like you could be a secretary sending on someone else's behalf, etc.

Comment: @Mehrdad No; the (SMTP) *envelope sender* address is like the return address on the outside of the envelope (where it gets sent if it can't be delivered), whereas the address in the `From` header is whatever you write on the piece of paper that you stick *inside* the envelope and that the mailman doesn't even know about.

Comment: I was thinking of the Sender: header when I wrote that, and it was just an example. Just saying it'd be nice to add an example like this to your answer.

Comment: @Michael What is the benefit of this? Why can't the email client display the "envelope"'s To/CC?

Comment: @SupremeGrandRuler Because the *recipient* information (in contrast to a possible Sender or Return-Path) is not contained in the email. Imagine the full recipient list was included, including the addresses the MUA got from the Bcc field (remember: SMTP (the envelope protocol) does not know about Bcc, it only knows about recipients) … That’d be a privacy issue (and a huge waste of space) not only on large mailing lists (operating by the same principle as Bcc does).

Comment: "For legitimate mail it usually is accurate enough" So this depends on what you call "accurate". As mentioned, classic mailing lists (e.g. Mailman based) operate by the same principle: they simply forward the email to the members of the list (+ some headers identifying the mailing list) without rewriting To and From headers (the distribution is handled on the SMTP envelope level only)—this is already "inaccurate" and "unwanted" to some and certainly breaks most DKIM signatures.

Comment: It may be worth noting that many mail severs injects a Received: entry into the headers that tells which recipient they received the message for. This header does not seem to have a standardized format though.

Comment: @poizan42 RFC 5821 section 7.6: "the optional FOR clause should be supplied with caution or not at all when multiple recipients are involved" RFC 5821 section 4.4: "If the FOR clause appears, it MUST contain exactly one `<path>` entry, even when multiple `RCPT` commands have been given" https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5321.txt

Comment: By the way, I have to say I'm not actually sure what you mean by the "envelope sender". Are you talking about the Return-Path header? Because I've never seen that referred to as the "sender" header but maybe I'm just not familiar with that usage.

Comment: @Mehrdad By *envelope sender* I mean the address that is used in the `MAIL FROM` command in the SMTP transaction and which is used as the return address by the mail server itself (most commonly in the case of needing to send a non-delivery notice after the SMTP transaction has finished). IIRC that address gets copied into a `Return-Path` header, but only during *final delivery*, so it wouldn't be there for example while a secondary mail exchanger is handling the message.

Answer (score 23):

tl;dr at bottom.

The SMTP protocol doesn't have the notion of CC or BCC recipients; this is a convention held by mail clients. The SMTP server only typically cares about routing information and data. This is an important distinction, because without this capability, BCC could not exist. As a legitimate BCC communication consider the following client transcript:

```
HELO from-mail-server.com
MAIL FROM:<john.smith@from-mail-server.com>
RCPT TO:<anonymous@another-mail-server.com>
DATA
From: "John Smith" <john.smith@from-mail-server.com>
To: "Jane Doe" <jane.doe@to-mail-server.com>
BCC: "Anonymous" <anonymous@another-mail-server.com>
Subject: Important Meeting Notice
Date: Monday, May 15, 2017 12:20 PM

This is an important meeting notice. We'll meet tomorrow.

.
```

Now, in this case, Anonymous was sent a message about this meeting. However, this version of the mail was *not* routed to Jane Doe; she knows nothing about Anonymous being notified. In contrast, Jane Doe will be sent the message with a different body and header:

```
HELO from-mail-server.com
MAIL FROM:<john.smith@from-mail-server.com>
RCPT TO:<jane.doe@to-mail-server.com>
DATA
From: "John Smith" <john.smith@from-mail-server.com>
To: "Jane Doe" <jane.doe@to-mail-server.com>
Subject: Important Meeting Notice
Date: Monday, May 15, 2017 12:20 PM

This is an important meeting notice. We'll meet tomorrow.

.
```

Here, since Anonymous was in the BCC, the message sent to Jane Doe did not include the BCC recipient list. Because of the BCC convention, the email envelope may not include recipients that actually received the message, and it may also include recipients that do not appear in the message headers.

As mentioned by [@JonasWielicki](https://superuser.com/users/122572/jonas-wielicki), which I also meant to include, is that the MUA (Mail User Agent) is typically responsible for sending the multiple emails that are required to implement BCC. Email servers do not know anything about BCC, and so the MUA must implement BCC by sending multiple emails with different email routes specified in the envelope headers. For this reason, BCCs typically take longer to send than normal emails, because different message bodies must be constructed and sent out individually.

This also helps with some email compliance rules. For example, a mail server may have rules configured to automatically BCC an archive email server (all emails sent to it are also archived), in which case the mail server might not even be a real recipient.

```
HELO from-mail-server.com
MAIL FROM:<john.smith@from-mail-server.com>
RCPT TO:<mail-archive@archive-server.com>
DATA
From: "John Smith" <john.smith@from-mail-server.com>
To: "Jane Doe" <jane.doe@to-mail-server.com>
BCC: "Anonymous" <anonymous@another-mail-server.com>
Subject: Important Meeting Notice
Date: Monday, May 15, 2017 12:20 PM

This is an important meeting notice. We'll meet tomorrow.

.
```

Here, the recipient is another party that is completely undisclosed to any of the recipients or even the sender. This is a feature of the protocol, typically used in relaying or archiving messages.

What this spam message did is take advantage of that behavior. It's a standard loophole that technically should work with any compliant mail server. Of course, many updated servers use "extensions" like DKIM to verify that such an email is authentic, but there are still many old mail servers out there that don't care, simply because it's tempting to not fix things that are not broken.

Also note how I've specified a Date header. This can be any arbitrary (but well-formatted) value; many clients will happily display any legal date range from the distant past to the far future. I have personally sent an email to myself years ago that will remain at the top of my mail box long after my life expectancy, as well as an email that predates my email account and my own birth.

### tl;dr

So, in summary, the sender spoofed an email, the originating mail server accepted/relayed it, your email server accepted it and stored it in your inbox, and your client faithfully displayed the data that was in your inbox to you, all without circumventing any security.  "Sending" security is often much less restricted than "receiving" security in that perspective, since POP3 almost always requires a username and password before you can access a mail box (you could theoretically circumvent this, but I don't know of any legitimate mail services that do).

Comment: You should note that stripping of Bcc is typically *not* handled by mail servers (the SMTP transcript you provided suggests otherwise, because the HELO sounds like a mail server and not a MUA). To provide a copy with Bcc header to the person addressed in that header requires extra work by the MUA by sending two separate emails.

Comment: @JonasWielicki That's a good point. I've added an edit to that effect.

Comment: If you add a bcc line to a delivered mail it is not blind anymore :)

Comment: Actually requiring the client to send multiple messages in the case of BCC is incorrect. It is perfectly sound to send just a single message. The SMTP client can list multiple `RCPT TO` instructions. The only requirement is that the receiving SMTP server either be the authoritative server for both recipients, or be willing to relay for any that it is not.

Answer (score 6):

SMTP and email are very old Internet services from an era when security and authentication were taken much less seriously (DNS is another example). The design of the protocol makes no effort to verify the authenticity of the sender address, and only validates the recipient address insofar as it is ensuring that the mail is deliverable.

Email is transmitted through the SMTP protocol. The SMTP protocol is relatively dumb; it provides a facility to transmit plaintext to an email address and very little more. The structure of this plaintext is defined by [RFC 5322](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322). The general idea is that the email text has metadata called a header, and the actual text body of the message. This email header is generated by the sender (none of it can be trusted) and contains fields like "to:", "from:", "subject:", etc...

The SMTP protocol does not (and is not supposed to) validate that the email headers match any of very few things defined in the SMTP protocol, which are essentially your email address and a sender email address that is never validated in any way.

Almost everything in an email message can be fake.

The only thing even remotely trustworthy about email contents today are DKIM signatures, which prove that the email was processed through an email server sanctioned by the domain registrant. Digging deeper, you would find that this scam email has no DKIM signature.

Comment: I'd add the final `Received:` header added by your own system to the trustworthy parts.

Answer (score 3):

Address `To` in email header is for information purposes and it is shown by the email client. The real recipient address is given with `RCPT TO` in SMTP. It is the same if you write letter, put in envelope, write Address-1 on envelope. Then go to courier, give another Address-2. The courier puts your envelope in bigger envelope with Address-2 and the shipment will go there. Your secretary (email client software) puts the external envelope to trash and show you the internal envelope with Address-1. You can see this with RAW view of email message.

Answer (score 2):

This is a slightly different look, based on examining headers.  The other answers handle the details of SMTP better than I could.

If you can get the full headers of your message, then search them for your address, you *may* find it in a field called `Envelope-to`, `Delivered-to` or `X-Apparently-to`.  The first is used by my mail provider, the second by Gmail; I've seen the third used as well.  These are different fields but for our purposes tend to mean the same thing: the mailbox to actually deliver the message into. I tested by sending from outlook (desktop version) with the recipient BCCed.

My mail provider also uses the `Delivered-To` field but for the mailbox name on their server.  This isn't my email address though it looks like one (think `ChrisH-$ACCOUNTNAME@$SERVER.mail.com`).

Outlook (combined with exchange server) on the other hand doesn't include in the headers a single field with the recipient's email address if you're listed as BCC.